# Sphinx 4 Transcription Time Index

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

How do I get time index (or frame number) in Sphinx 4 when I set it to transcribe an audio file?

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
audioURL = ...
AudioFileDataSource dataSource = (AudioFileDataSource) cm.lookup("audioFileDataSource");
dataSource.setAudioFile(audioURL, null);

Result result;
while ((result = Recognizer.recognize()) != null) {
  Token token = result.getBestToken();
  //DoubleData data = (DoubleData) token.getData();
  //long frameNum = data.getFirstSampleNumber(); // data seem always null
  String resultText = token.getWordPath(false, false);
  ...
}
```

I tried to get time of transcription from result/token objects, e.g. similar to what a subtitler do.  I've found Result.getFrameNumber() and Token.getFrameNumber() but they appear to return the number of frames decoded and not the time (or frame) where the result was found in the context of entire audio file.

I looked at AudioFileDataSource.getDuration()[=private] and the Recognizer classes but haven't figure out how to get the needed transcribed time-index..

Ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Frame number is the time multiplied by frame rate which is 100 frames/second.

Anyway, please find the patch for subtitles demo which returns timings here:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1380033926.26218.12.camel%40localhost.localdomain&forum_name=cmusphinx-devel

The patch applies to subversion trunk, not to the 1.0-beta version.

Please note that this part is under major refactoring, so the API will be obsolete soon. However, I hope you will be able to create subtitles with just few calls without all current complexity.